# NotImplementedError: data_source='iex' is not implemented

Tags: pandas, pandas-datareader, elixir-iex

I am trying to get some stock data through pandas_datareader in jupyter notebook. I was using google, but that does not work anymore, so I am using iex.

```
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import datetime
start = datetime.datetime(2015,1,1)
end = datetime.datetime(2017,1,1)
facebook = web.DataReader('FB','iex',start,end)
```

However, it comes back with the following error.

```
NotImplementedError: data_source='iex' is not implemented
```

Can anyone help me how to solve this issue please?

Answer (score 1):

Many DataReader sources are deprecated, see updated list [here](https://pandas-datareader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/remote_data.html#remote-data-access).

Many now require API key, IEX is one of them:

> Usage of all IEX readers now requires an [API key](https://pandas-datareader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/remote_data.html#iex).

Get API key from [IEX Cloud Console](https://iexcloud.io/), which can be stored in the IEX_API_KEY environment variable. Just execute this is separate cell in Jupyter Notebook:

`os.environ["IEX_API_KEY"] = "pk_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"`

With [free IEX account](https://iexcloud.io/pricing/) you can get 500,000 free Core messages/mo.

Answer (score 1):

data.DataReader using 'iex' might have been discontinued. Use 'yahoo'.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: The chart api was removed on June 15, 2019. Currently, using this api to try to download any stock data such as SPY will return nothing but an `HTTP 403` error. The functions of deprecated APIs are now transferred to their new API, IEX Cloud, which requires a unique token per user in any request. So to get over with it read this [documentation here](https://iexcloud.io/docs/api/).

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the module. Go to terminal and type:

```
conda install pandas-datareader
```

Answer (score 0):

this should resolve it: `pip install git+https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader.git`